# What require('./.'); means?

Tags: node.js, pixi.js

Found this strange looking URL which is working by the way.

```
var _ = require('./.');
```

Can someone explain what this will do in reality and why they are doing it ?

Comment: I'm voting for a question to be closed because there's no such line in linked file. Any way, this would mean what the answer suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be a typo, but it is normalized to `.`.

If you're ever curious about how a path is resolved in Node.js, you can use `path` methods and `require.resolve` to see what is going on.

```
> path.normalize('./.')
'.'
> path.normalize('././././././././.')
'.'
> require.resolve('./.') // assuming `index.js` exists...
'/path/to/index.js'
```

Comment: process.cwd and path.resolve aren't really relevant here because module paths aren't resolved with cwd. require.resolve is relevant. `path.normalize('./.')` could also demonstrate that `.` and `./.` is same thing.